# How can I make Dired buffer names include the full path?

Tags: dired

I often have many `dired` buffers open, including some for folders that have identical names. Occasionally, this causes me to switch to the wrong one, so I am looking for a way to fix this.

Currently, if I have multiple identically-named folders open in `dired`, then my buffer list looks something like this:

```
foo
foo<2>
bar
foo<3>
bar<2>
```

I would like to include the full path (or some portion of it) in the buffer name so I can see which folder I am actually switching to. I would prefer to do it like this:

```
foo</full/path/to/foo>
foo</another/path>
```

and so on. I could also settle for e.g.:

```
/full/path/to/foo
/another/path/foo
```

but I would prefer the former, because it will usually be easier to find the buffer I want by folder name first, and full path second. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this behavior by using `uniquify` with the following settings:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward-angle-brackets
      uniquify-min-dir-content 999)
```

Note however that uniquify works globally, not only on dired buffers.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I will wait and see if there is a solution that does give a full path before I accept an answer.

Comment: I just added a note about `uniquify-min-dir-content`, which should help you with that.  Note however, that this is a global setting: it applies to all buffers, not just dired buffers!

Answer (score 6):

In my .emacs I set full paths for Dired buffers this way:

```
(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; Set name of dired buffers to absolute directory name.
        ;; Use `generate-new-buffer-name' for vc-directory
        ;; which creates duplicate buffers.
        (rename-buffer (generate-new-buffer-name dired-directory))))
```

Comment: One advantage of this: you can customize how you name dired buffers, such as with a "dired: " prefix or something